# Should "that basically" be between commas, or just "basically"?

Tags: commas

I would say that, basically, anything that can be reasonably considered to be an investment in the future.

Comment: Welcome to ELL ! Can you be more clear about your question? maybe adding a little bit more context? Can you explain how do you want to use *basically*, and what wuold you like to say ?

Comment: The word ***that*** is always OPTIONAL in such contexts, and whether you include it or not makes no difference to the punctuation requirements of an utterance. But in the exact context specified, the word ***basically*** is a PARENTHETICAL element (also "optional", but not in the same way). Parenthetical elements are ***always*** set off / delineated by commas (the utterance must remain syntactically valid whether or not the parenthetical element ***and*** its enclosing commas are present).

Comment: @Liiuc This is something I transcribed from an audio file. "Rich is not associated with tools" in this case. The speaker saying this sentence made a slight pause before tools.